# What causes an "Error in the web application" error when using Watson's document conversion service?

Tags: node.js, pdf, stream, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am trying to convert some PDF files into answer units with Watson's *Document Conversion* service.  These files are all zipped up into one big .zip file, which is uploaded to my Bluemix server running a Node.js application.  The application unzips the files in memory and tries to send each one in turn to the conversion service:

```
var document_conversion = watson.document_conversion(dcCredentials);

function createCollection(res, solrClient, docs)
   {
   for (var doc in docs) //docs is an array of objects describing the pdf files
      {
      console.log("Converting: %s", docs[doc].filename);

      //make a stream of this pdf file
      var rs = new Readable;    //create the stream
      rs.push(docs[doc].data);  //add pdf file (string object) to stream
      rs.push(null);        //end of stream marker

      document_conversion.convert(
         {
         file: rs,
         conversion_target: "ANSWER_UNITS"
         }, 
         function (err, response) 
            {
            if (err) 
               {
               console.log("Error converting doc: ", err);
        .
        .
        .
        etc...
```

Every time, the conversion service returns error **400** with the description *"Error in the web application"*.

After scratching my head for two days trying to figure out the cause of this rather unhelpful error message, I have pretty much decided that the problem must be that the conversion service can't figure out what type of file is being sent, since there's no filename associated with it.  This of course is just a guess on my part, but I can't test this theory because I don't know how to provide that information to the service without actually writing each file to disk and reading it back.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Interesting... someone commented on this to ask for more information, and I made a comment to provide the information.  Then the next day both comments disappeared.  Is that normal on Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated: The problem is in how the underlying form-data library handles Streams: [It doesn't calculate the length of Streams](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/tree/v1.0.0-rc3#notes) (with the exception of file and request steams, which it has extra logic to handle).

> `getLengthSync()` method DOESN'T calculate length for streams, use `knownLength` options as workaround.

I found two ways around this. Calculate the length yourself and pass it as an option:

```js
document_conversion.convert({
  file: { value: rs, options: { knownLength: 12345 } }
  ...
```

Or use a Buffer:

```js
document_conversion.convert({
  file: { value: myBuffer, options: {} }
  ...
```

---

The reason you were getting a `400` response was because the Content-Length header of your request was incorrectly calculated: The length was too small for the request, causing the MIME part of the request to be truncated (and not closed).

I suspect this is due to the `Readable` stream not providing a length or size for your content when the request library calculates the size of the entity.

Also, apologies for the useless error message. We'll make that better.

Comment: Thank you for investigating this.  Being a stream, however, I would think that the server would calculate the size after it has been all read. Streams typically don't have a "length" iirc.  I looked at the `Readable` object in a file-based app that works and couldn't find anything that showed the data length.
The API shows a configuration object that should be passed in, but it only shows one parameter, the required conversion target.  If there are others I can't find them - I was hoping there was one to describe the incoming file mime/type.

Comment: The content length is passed to the server as an HTTP request header; it should be calculated by the client or omitted. From my continued digging, I think it's a problem with the form-data library the Node.js SDK uses. If you're looking to describe the file's mime/content-type, that should be sent as the Content-Type in the file's part of the multi-part request.

Comment: Awesome!  I wasn't able to get it to work with the knownLength option (got the same error message as before), but using a Buffer did the trick.  

The service always returns exactly zero answer units, at least in my small test zip. But at least I'm moving forward.  Maybe I'm not creating the Buffer correctly - the PDF is a String at that point so I'm using `new Buffer(pdf)`.  Could be that you can't represent a PDF properly in a String, I don't know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The code below iterate a zip file and convert each document to `ANSWER_UNITS`.
It uses `node-unzip-2` and the zip file **documents.zip** contains these [3 sample files](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/document-conversion-nodejs/tree/master/public/data).

```
var unzip  = require('node-unzip-2');
var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var fs     = require('fs');

var document_conversion = watson.document_conversion({
  username: 'USERNAME',
  password: 'PASSWORD',
  version_date: '2015-12-01',
  version:  'v1'
});

function convertDocument(doc) {
  document_conversion.convert({
    file: doc,
    conversion_target: document_conversion.conversion_target.ANSWER_UNITS,
  }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(doc.path,'error:',err);
    } else {
      console.log(doc.path,'OK');
      // hide the results for now
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
    }
  });
}

fs.createReadStream('documents.zip')
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .on('entry', function (entry) {
    if (entry.type === "File") {
      convertDocument(entry);
    } else {
      // Prevent out of memory issues calling autodrain for non processed entries
      entry.autodrain();
    }
  });
```

Example output:

```
$ node app.js
 sampleHTML.html OK
 sampleWORD.docx OK
 samplePDF.pdf OK
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not address my question.  I can get the zip file transferred and unzipped without a problem; it's failing when sending the unzipped files (already in memory) to the document conversion service. I'd like to avoid writing anything to the file system on the server, since it's all already in memory.

Comment: I'm not writing anything to the file system. I'm reading the zip file, parsing it and iterating on each entry.